# Unable to integrate Hazelcast version 4.2 with Spring Boot 2.3.6.RELEASE

Tags: java, spring-boot, hazelcast

I am using Spring Boot version 2.3.6.RELEASE in my application and added hazelcast version 4.2 and wanted to use spring-integration-hazelcast of version 3.0.0 as this only is compatible with hazelcast 4.2 version.

But getting below error during build:

```
Require upper bound dependencies error for org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-core:5.3.4.RELEASE paths to dependency are:
+-package:ocapi-admin-service:4.0.0-SNAPSHOT
  +-org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-core:5.3.4.RELEASE
and
+-package:ocapi-admin-service:4.0.0-SNAPSHOT
  +-org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-hazelcast:3.0.0
    +-org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-core:5.3.4.RELEASE (managed) <-- org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-core:5.4.0
]
```

Below is the pom snippet:

```xml
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-integration-core</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-integration-hazelcast</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.hazelcast</groupId>
                <artifactId>hazelcast</artifactId>
                <version>4.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.hazelcast</groupId>
                <artifactId>hazelcast-spring</artifactId>
                <version>4.2</version>
            </dependency>
```

Comment: You cannot and shouldn't mix different versions of frameworks. With this you are mixing different `spring-integration` partgs, leading to also different spring jars leading to all sorts of issues. Use the same version as for the other `spring-integration` parts or down- or upgrade Spring Boot to include  aversion you need.

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to update the version of `spring-integration-core` to at least `5.4.0`.

You don't specify it in the code snippet from `pom.xml` you shared, but I guess it must be taken from somewhere else since you have it in the logs. Try changing this dependency to the following one:

```
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-integration-core</artifactId>
                <version>5.4.0</version>
            </dependency>
```

Comment: One shouldn't mix differnt versions of jars from a single framework, this will lead to all sorts of issues.